# How to create an Expand All Button for Mat-table so that it expands every row in the table in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am using Angular Mat-Table and have created a table with expandable rows just like the one below in Angular 8:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qykjaloknex?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

I wanted to know if there was a way that I can create an expand all button that will expand every single row at one time instead of having to click on each row at a time to expand it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by introducing a property that you can toggle (via a button for example) that you check in addition to the `expandedElement`.

Add a button in the template to toggle the expand/collapse all:

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="toggle()">{{allRowsExpanded ? 'Collapse' : 'Expand'}}</button>
```

Change the condition for a row to be expanded:

```
<div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="(element == expandedElement || allRowsExpanded) ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
```

And wire it up in the component:

```
allRowsExpanded: boolean = false;

public toggle() {
  this.allRowsExpanded = !this.allRowsExpanded;
  this.expandedElement = null;
}
```

> Have a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gfny52?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html) stackblitz for a working example.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use this to get it to work.